# Unity：AndroidAPKに書き出すとアニメーションしない

Tags: unity3d

Unityにおいて、
MMD4Mecanimを使用し変換したモデルで、　Android に書き出すとアニメーションしません。
unity上のプレビューでは動きます。
またアニメーション以外のプログラムは動いています

Unityのバージョンは5.2
MMD4Mecanim　20150821

試した事
・MMD4Mecanimを使わず、AndroidAPKにする→アニメーションする
・Unityのバージョンを4.6まで落としてみる→アニメーションしない
・PCへの書き出し→アニメーションする

Comment: 解決しました。
MMD4Mecanim　が新しいバージョンよりモバイル書き出しに対応していないためでした。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は原因と解決策を自分で回答投稿するのがマナーのようです。解決済みか分からなくなるためだと思われます。回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMD4Mecanim　が新しいバージョンよりモバイル書き出しに対応していないためでした

過去のバージョンではモバイル書き出しに対応していたため、ネット上では「これでできる」という解説が行われたままのものが存在します。